# Copying an object using a constructor, Java

Tags: java, constructor, object, copy

So lets say I want to make a deep copy of an object, but using its contsructor. So I have:

```
public class PositionList {
    private Position[] data = new Position[0];
    private int size = 0;

public PositionList(PositionList other, boolean deepCopy) {
    if (deepCopy==true){
        size=other.getSize();
        for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        data[i]=other.data[i];
    }
    else {
        data=other.data;
        size = other.size;
```

And so say I have this being called:

```
PositionList list = new PositionList();
PositionList acopy = new PositionList(list, true);
```

What I am doing, however, is incorrect, and Im not sure why..

Comment: That boolean check should be `if (deepCopy == true)` or even `if (deepCopy)`, right? :)

Comment: Ya that too..that was just pending code..I was trying to figure out the others stuff

Comment: Writing `if (deepCopy==true)` is gauche. Please write `if (deepCopy)` instead.

Comment: Why aren't you implementing  `Object.clone()`?

Comment: How would I use clone in a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your deep copy logic:

```
size=other.getSize();
for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    data[i]=other.data[i];
```

You are setting the `size` field (which is redundant with the `data` array) but are not assigning a new array to the `data` field, which is presumably the whole point of your "deep" copy.  You should initialize `data` to the other's `size` (or `other.data.length`):

```
data = new Position[other.data.length];
for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    data[i]=other.data[i];
```

(And get rid of `size` all together)

Comment: Wait why would I get rid of size?

Comment: @fprime, what value would `size` *ever* contain that doesn't match `data.length`?